# How to understand the etymology from the American Heritage Dictionary?

Tags: etymology, dictionary

I look up the word ['frangible'](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=frangible). Its etymology shows

[Middle English, from Old French, from Medieval Latin frangibilis, from Latin frangere, to break; see bhreg- in the Appendix of Indo-European roots.]

Does it mean this is

- a Middle English word
- borrowed from Old French
- borrowed from Medieval Latin 'frangibilis'
- derived from Latin 'frangere'

Comment: You don't mention the reference to PIE *_bhreg-_; that's the most interesting of all. That's even more distantly related, but it sums up the basic idea and [shows how a word (in this case the English word _break_)](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/_/roots.aspx?type=Indo-European&root=bhreg-) has had a pretty good two and a half millennia, spawning descendants of all shapes and sizes.

Comment: Should be posted at [english.se].

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it would be better on ELU or Language Learning.

Comment: This is about how to read a resource on etymology. It's on-topic (as much as the front matter of the dictionary would have easily answered the question).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, mostly. It is first attested in Middle English; it is borrowed from Old French *frangible*, which is borrowed from Medieval *frangibilis* (an alternative analysis which they do not adopt is that the Middle English comes from Medieval Latin and not Old French). The step "from frangere" involves a different sense of "from". The chain from *frangible* to *frangibilis* is a series of historical "same word, added to a different language". Latin *frangibilis* isn't "from" frangere in the same way, rather, *frangere, frangere, frangō* etc all derive synchronically in Latin from the same root, and one of the conventions for identifying roots in Latin is to give the infinitive (or, the 1st singular present).